# Expand Bulma column horizontally after another column end

Tags: css, bulma

I am trying to do the first design in Bulma framework;
I have three column design for the site content part.

However I'd like to have the middle column grow to full height once the second column ends.

Currently the design looks like this[image]

What I would like to achieve is for the column with the articles to grow to full width after the end of the Evens Calendar column.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
  <main id="site-content">    
<div class="columns is-multiline">
  <div id="site-content-sidebar-left" class="column is-one-fifth">
    <h2 class="title is-2">News</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="site-content-primary" class="column">
    <article class="column">
      <h2 class="title">2nd article</h2>
      <p>jskjdskjdksjkdsjsd</p>
      <span>
        March 1, 2019 | 
        <a href="http://localhost/author/mark/" title="Posts by Mark Stopka" rel="author">Mark Stopka</a> | 
          <a href="http://localhost/category/uncategorized/" rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a>            </span>
        <hr />
      </article>
      <article class="column">
        <h2 class="title">Hello world!</h2>
        <p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>
        <span>
          February 28, 2019 | 
          <a href="http://localhost/author/mark/" title="Posts by Mark Stopka" rel="author">Mark Stopka</a> | 
          <a href="http://localhost/category/uncategorized/" rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a>            </span>
        <hr />
      </article>
    </div>
    <div id="site-content-sidebar-right" class="column is-one-fifth">
      <h2 class="title is-3">Events Calendar</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my styles are as follows:

```
#site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#site-content {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1rem;
}

#site-content-sidebar-left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#site-content-primary {

}

#site-content-sidebar-right {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: fit-content;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

How do I make `id="site-content-primary"` expand below `#site-content-sidebar-right` when it is no longer occupied by a content?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved, I've moved

```
<div id="site-content-sidebar-right" class="column is-one-fifth">
  <h2 class="title is-3">Events Calendar</h2>
</div>
```

into `<div id="site-content-primary" class="column">` and set it to `float: right;`.